# Is there an Ethereum Testnet Android Wallet?

Tags: ether, wallets, android

I am looking for a testnet-specific Android wallet app to load with a few Ropsten test Ether, for a web app I'm building. But for the life of me, I cannot find such an app for Ethereum.

For Bitcoin I'm using "MyCelium Testnet", but is there a testnet-specific equivalent for Ethereum? My web app generates a QR code for payment for a service, and I want to test it end to end.

Many thanks.
Russ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check CYPHER. We use it extensively on ropsten in the IOS version. I think that the Android version be available.